# Scoping associations and the Apartment gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ransack, apartment-gem

I hope I can explain this correctly.

I have the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :companies, through: :enrollments, dependent: :destroy

class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :users, through: :enrollments
```

These are all in the public tenant in the apartment gem.  Company is the tenant.  The idea here is that Users are associated to Companies via Enrollments.  I have other info in Enrollments so I didn't go with STI.

I can call current_user.enrollments etc. but what I really want is a has_one type association where you get the enrollment from the current tenant.

I added this:

```
  def enrollment
    company = Company.where(tenant_name: Apartment::Tenant.current).last
    company.enrollments.where(user_id: self.id).last
  end
```

Which works when called but you can't search on it with Ransack etc

For the Ransack a query like `enrollments_somefield_eq=somevalue` works fine but it searches all the Enrollments but I want just the enrollments from the current company.  I have seen where you can add a condition to the association but I don't think I can get the tenant id in the model to use it.

Any ideas here?

**UPDATE**

I am close here - after a ton of Googling I cobbled together this:

```
has_many :active_enrollments, -> { joins(:company).where("companies.tenant_name = '#{Apartment::Tenant.current}'") }, class_name: 'Enrollment'
```

I really want:

```
has_one :active_enrollment, -> { joins(:company).where("companies.tenant_name = '#{Apartment::Tenant.current}'").last }, class_name: 'Enrollment'
```

but this does not work. As there is really only ever one enrollment per company and user.  This may be close enough because I can query `active_enrollments` via ransack and the scope is applied etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ransack: How to use existing scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949915/ransack-how-to-use-existing-scope)

Comment: or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849054/how-to-filter-results-with-ransack

Comment: Hmmm... I was close.  I have a boolean in my Enrollment table.  If I search for the true records it works and if I search for the false records it works but I get the results repeated.

Comment: Ok... I guess you have to add result(distinct: true) to filter out the duplicates

Answer (score 0):

I forgot I had asked this already and I have answered it over here:

[Scoping an association search with Ransack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129520/scoping-an-association-search-with-ransack/34141992)