# Scoping an association search with Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ransack

I have a `User` model with an `Enrollment` model associated with it.  A User can have many Enrollments but each Enrollment only has one `Company`.

My `Enrollment` model has a `flag_contractor` boolean.  So if I have a `User` search such as `:enrollment_flag_contractor false` I can get inconsistant results as I am trying to scope my enrolments for the current company (via the Apartment gem).

For example I have a user that has an enrollment in two separate companies, one with flag_contractor = true and one with flag_contractor = false.

I have already scoped the `User` model to only have the Users with enrollments in the current company but Ransack seems to still drill down in the association and search across all the enrollments.

I have tried to add a Ransack scope to my `Enrollment` model:

```
scope :active, -> (company_id) { where(company_id: company_id) }
```

then modified my Users controler:

```
@users = @search.result(distinct: true, active: current_company.id).paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

but with out success.

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be the best answer as it's the only way (and may be the best) to do this.

Here are the scopes I now have in my `User` model:

```
scope :enrolled_old, -> { joins(:companies).where("companies.tenant_name = '#{Apartment::Tenant.current}'") }
scope :enrolled, -> (company_id) { joins(:enrollments).where("enrollments.company_id = '#{company_id}'") }
```

The old one didn't work.  Not sure why.  If I pass the company_id into the scope the scope works.  They seemed to both work from the console.

So now in my Pundit User policy I have:

```
company = Company.where(tenant_name: Apartment::Tenant.current).last
User.joins(:enrollments).where("enrollments.company_id = '#{company.id}'")
```

That works and it actually helps lock down my Policy better.